# Differential equation not following rules for constant coefficient ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following ODE:

$y'''+y= 0$

Yields the following characteristic equation

$r^3+1=0$

with 3 repeated roots of -1. Thus according to the rules the solution should be:

$y(x) = c_1e^{-x}+c_2xe^{-x}+c_3x^2e^{-x}$

However when I plug it back into the original ODE I don't get zero. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I seems that you solves $y'''-y=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r^3+1=(r+1)(r^2-r+1)=0 \implies r=-1,\frac{1\pm \sqrt 3i}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$(x+1)^3=(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)$$
but
$$(x^3+1)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
so the roots are not repeated

Answer (score 1):

No, 
$$
r^3+1=(r+1)(r^2-r+1)=(r+1)((r-\tfrac12)^2+\tfrac34)
$$
has only a single root at $r=-1$ and a pair of complex conjugate roots that divide the unit circle equally in parts of 120°.